# Multiple QRCode detection from video stream

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, zxing, emgucv

I am making a program in c# that must detect and scan Qr-codes from a tag (using security cameras) that people glue to their chest, and as a second layer of security must also capture their faces and match them in a database. Now, i was able of dealing with the face recognition just fine, but the program fails to read more than one Qr-code at a time. How could i deal with this? I am using ZXing's library aswell as Emgu.cv. Are there better options?
My code for QR-Reading is:

```
        bitmap = frame.Bitmap;
        txtQreader.Text = Qrreader(bitmap); //it's inside an if, not that it matters :p


    private string Qrreader(Bitmap x)
{
    BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader { AutoRotate = true, TryHarder = true };
    Result result = reader.Decode(x);
    string decoded = result.ToString().Trim();
    return decoded;
}
```

Comment: You need to include more information see how to create a Minimum  Complete and Verifiable Example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  But my guess is that you are passing in an entire image to the `Qrreader`. You should segment out each QR in the image, then pass them one at a time to `Qrreader`

Comment: @andrew Didn't knew it lacked information, im sorry (new to the stack). That is exactly my issue. How to segment out each QR.

Comment: Welcome to Stack. This might be enough information for a regular programming question, but for computer vision problems you should include 3 images. `1. input 2. current (incorrect) output 3. desired output` Looking at your code I see no issues, but showing the images would help reveal the problem. If you pass in an entire `frame`  with multiple QR codes in one frame, maybe `Qrreader` only decodes the first code it finds. I think you need to identify each QR code. Then create a subimage with only the QR codes, then send the subimage to `Qrreader` have you tried this approach?

Comment: @andrew It's solved, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is solved after consulting another website it was told to me that using IMultiBarcodereader will return an array with all the decoded information contained in multiple codes. Also `reader.Decode(x)` must be made into `reader.Decodemultiple(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may first define the reader as `QRCodeMultiReader` and then define a vector to contain the results, so it would be as follow:

```
QRCodeMultiReader reader;
vector<Ref<Result>> results(reader.decodeMultiple(bitmap, DecodeHints(DecodeHints::TRYHARDER_HINT)));
```

As you may know a `BinaryBitmap` should be created.